# Error with WP7 Silverlight - No Overload for "" Matches Delegate

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, twitter, overloading

I am new to WP7 programming and I have been following this tutorial

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/18/building-a-windows-phone-7-twitter-application-using-silverlight.aspx

However I have run into a number of errors and I was wondering if anyone could tell me why. I have been over and over the code and as far as I can see it is all correct.

The first issue is a:

> No overload for "twitter_DownloadsStringCompleted" matches delegate system.net.downloadStringEventHandler

Here is the code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WebClient twitter = new WebClient();

    twitter.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(twitter_DownloadStringCompleted);
    twitter.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=" + username.Text));
}

void twitter_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public class TwitterItem
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string ImageSource { get; set; }
}

void twitter_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
        return;
    XElement xmlTweets = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

    listBox1.ItemsSource = from tweet in xmlTweets.Descendants("status")
                           select new TwitterItem
                           {
                               ImageSource = tweet.Elemend("user").Element("profile_image_url").Value,
                               Message = tweet.Element("text").Value,
                               UserName = tweet.Element("user").Element("SCreen_name").Value
                           };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have two copies of `twitter_DownloadStringCompleted` one with code, one without. Is this intentional?

Comment: Try readding the event handler again and make sure you let Visual Studio creates the handler for you. It will have the correct parameter profile.

Comment: 0
 
down vote 
accept  Rhys here. The two copies are according to the tutorial. So I assume that is correct.

How would I let Visual studio create this handler for me? Sorry for my ignorance, but I am very new to this and current;y just trying to learn from the tutorial I linked at the top.

Comment: If you type in `twitter.DownloadStringCompleted +=` Visual Studio should prompt to fill in the rest - just hit tab twice. This will create a handler of the correct profile. There shouldn't be two copies of the same handler - that looks like an error in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument list for your completed event handler should be:

```
void twitter_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
```

note it's `DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs` not `DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler`.

See this image from the tutorial:

[image: screen shot from tutorial]

Comment: Thanks for that Chris.. I actually missed a few things. One was the above, another was Adding Using.System.Xml.linq and also adding the reference. I aappreciate your help.